# Find anomalies in records of categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset with $m$ observations and $p$ categorical variables (nominal), each variable $X_1,X_2...X_p$ has several different classes (possible values).

Ultimately I am looking for a way to find anomalies i.e. to identify rows for which the combination of values seems incorrect with respect to the data I saw so far.

So far I was thinking about building a model to predict the value for each column and then build some metric to evaluate how different the actual row is from the predicted row. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you please share an example of your data and one row you think should be labeled as an outlier?

Comment: How big is P? And how many observations have you got?

Answer (score 1):

You could make one-hot-encodings of your categories, and then run an auto-encoder, and finally look at reconstruction errors. Those samples with the highest reconstruction errors are the most likely to be "abnormal". For an example of a workflow using H2O you can look at the [following blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/credit-card-fraud-detection-using-autoencoders-in-h2o-399cbb7ae4f1).